# compiling static library for windows in cygwin

Tags: gcc, compilation, cygwin, mingw

I'm trying to compile a library (dxflib) for use in windows using cygwin.

I'm loosely following the instructions found here: http://www.ribbonsoft.com/doc/dxflib/2.5/reference/dxflib-reference-manual.pdf

I can get it to compile to make a .a library (ie a unix static library), using 'make' but obviously I'm using cygwin because I want to compile a .lib for use in windows.

When I try to use 'MinGW32-make' (or any other derivative I can think of) cygwin claims that it doesn't exist. I've reinstalled all options with mingw or gcc or g++ remotely in their name in cygwin.

Does anybody know how to get it to compile from the makefile to produce a .lib? Thanks.

Comment: Why? The MinGW linker will accept the .a file just fine.

Comment: I'm only using (in fact only installed) cygwin in order to use dxflib in a wider windows project I intend to compile with visual studio.

Comment: In general, Cygwin binaries are *not* compatible with Windows binaries. MinGW binaries *are* compatible, sort of, but I think you need to know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm following instructions to compile dxflib under windows, for use in the windows environment. The only reason I am using cygwin to do so at all is because the documentation (above) instructed me to, thus I assume it produces, using mingw32-make, a .lib file for use in Windows. My problem is despite installing everything I can't find (anything like) mingw32-make in my environment.

Comment: Oh, Cygwin has some support for building MinGW binaries, but as far as I know `mingw32-make` comes from the MinGW or MSYS packages, not Cygwin. See [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started).